# Is there any way to remove a specific number of characters before a string and is it possible to make the number of removed charaters variable

Tags: python, encryption

I'm trying to create a substitution cipher for a class I'm taking, and I have it figured out except for the output of my program. I am concatenating the user's original string with the encoded string and I am wondering if it is possible to just remove the original user's input from the outputted string?

Input: hello world

```
english_alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
al_bhed_alphabet = 'YPLTAVKREZGMSHUBXNCDIJFQOWypltavkrezgmshubxncdijfqow'

def encode(user_string):
    for letter in user_string:
        if letter in english_alphabet:
            user_string += al_bhed_alphabet[english_alphabet.find(letter)]
        else:
            user_string += letter
    print(user_string)
```

output: hello worldrammu funmt

I have tried using a few different methods that I have seen but none can get the desired result, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you concatenating to the original string instead of creating a new string?

Comment: Create your own empty string, e. g. `result = ''`, add characters to it and finally print it.

Comment: Anyway, to answer your question: Use a slice: `return user_string[len(user_string)//2:]`

Comment: @Barmar I dont really know I, just hadnt thought of it. How wouuld i go about doing it?

Comment: The same way, except you concatenate to the new variable instead of `user_string`.

Answer (score 0):

Python already provides a native builtin mapping for strings with the [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) method:

```
translate_from = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
translate_to = 'YPLTAVKREZGMSHUBXNCDIJFQOWypltavkrezgmshubxncdijfqow'

translator = str.maketrans(translate_from, translate_to)

"hello world".translate(translator)
# rammu funmt
```

---

If you still want to remove a prefix, you can also use the builtin [str.removeprefix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix) method:

```
'hello worldrammu funmt'.removeprefix('hello world')
# rammu funmt
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) You can simply just create a new string `res` and concatenate in the new string.

**Code:**

```
english_alphabet='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
al_bhed_alphabet='YPLTAVKREZGMSHUBXNCDIJFQOWypltavkrezgmshubxncdijfqow'

def encode(user_string):
    res=""
    for letter in user_string:
        if letter in english_alphabet:
            res+=al_bhed_alphabet[english_alphabet.find(letter)]
        else:
            res+=letter
    return res

print(encode("hello world"))  #rammu funmt
```

(2)Encoding by ***list comprehension***.

**Code:**

```
english_alphabet='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
al_bhed_alphabet='YPLTAVKREZGMSHUBXNCDIJFQOWypltavkrezgmshubxncdijfqow'

def encode(user_string):
    return ''.join([al_bhed_alphabet[english_alphabet.find(letter)] if letter in english_alphabet else letter for letter in user_string])

print(encode("hello world")) #rammu funmt
```